# Convert C# Library To MSTest Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, testing, mstest

I have some class libraries with NUnit tests, and I want to convert the project to use the VS 2008 MsTest integration. (Right click add test etc.)

Is there and easy way to convert or do I need to edit the csproj manually.

Thanks

Comment: Related post - [How to convert an existing assembly to a ms unit test assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3012571/465053)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the following to the property group in the csproj file

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: Note that this only goes into the first `<PropertyGroup>`, the one that doesn't have the `Condition` property (`<PropertyGroup Condition="...">`).

Comment: Plus you need to reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework in order to be able to run tests.