# How to convert an existing assembly to a ms unit test assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, built-in

In Visual Studio 2010 Pro, how can I easily convert a classic assembly to a ms unit test assembly ?

It there a flag to activate in the .csproj file ?

Comment: is there any chance you could actually accept the *correct* answer to this question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey which one do you class as correct? The answer currently marked as accepted (by Dror Helper) seems to work for me.

Comment: Related post - [Convert C# Library To MSTest Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1185840/465053)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem is that test projects are "marked" on the project file - you can convert a class library to Test project follow these four simple steps:

1. Unload the project (.prj) file and then open it for update.
2. add the following line to the project
   C#:

   ```
   <Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
     <AssemblyName>....</AssemblyName>
     <!-- add this line below -->
     <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```

   VB - `<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-
   5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>`
3. Re-load the project back
4. Run you (now working) tests

*Note that you'll need to manually add reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll in order to be able to use test related attributes*

Update: In the upcoming MSTest V2 this will not be nesessery as MSTest becomes a NuGet package which works just like NUnit/XUnit

Comment: Ah, the clean intuitive interface of VS2010, what a wonderful solution!

Comment: For converting it back to a c# library, simply remove that line altogether.

Comment: Hopefully the next MSTest version (V2) will make this obsolete and we could use simple class library https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/06/17/taking-the-mstest-framework-forward-with-mstest-v2/

Comment: It may also be worth noting that you have to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` for access to the required attributes.  Also, works in VS 2017.

Comment: Keep in mind that the default "unit test" project in VS2017 is no longer a special project, instead it's a class Library with two NuGet packages

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 you can add nuget packages `MSTest.TestAdapter` and `MSTest.TestFramework` to your C# project and from then on use `[TestClass]` with `[TestMethod]` attributes. They will be automatically discovered and listed in the `Test Explorer`. A manual added `ProjectTypeGuids` is not needed to enable tests.

```
// MyFancyClassTests.cs

namespace MyTests
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class MyFancyClassTest
    {
        private readonly MyFancyClass _MyFancyClass;

        public MyFancyClassTest()
        {
            _MyFancyClass= new MyFancyClass();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void MyFancyClass_UninitializedName_ReturnsEmptyString()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, _MyFancyClass.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Unit Test Project is only Class Library which have classes with attribute [TestClass], and .csproj file doesn't have any flags. You can add class to your project and set attribute [TestClass] and it will be test class.

Comment: Ok, but I want to start unit test in Visual Studio 2010. Even if I add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework and in my class i use [TestClass] and  [TestMethod] attribute, I can't view my methods in the Test View window in VS2010.

Comment: You might have to build the code first before the methods appear in the window. Simply adding the attributes to the code, and not building, does not update the test view window (I think!).

Comment: I had the same issue. After adding a class with the [TestClass] attribute containing some methods with the [TestMethod] attribute and rebuilding, the tests did not appear in the Test View. Adding <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids> to the csproj file fixed it.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vststest/thread/2192fac0-0de7-45c6-872a-2be49e95ce2c/

Comment: Teevus your comment contains the best answer to this question. Maybe you should add it as a real answer so we can vote it up :)